# I want to round off to the nearest half hour meaning that If I arrive at 11:15 and leave 11:50, car will still be charged for one half an hour not two

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to round off to the nearest half hour meaning that If I arrive at 11:15 and leave 11:50, car will still be charged for one half an hour not two. I have tried for the last couple of hours to fix it but I cant seem to know what to do (I recently started learning programming)

```
import math
PARKING_COST = 1.75
TAX_RATE = 1.13
startHour = eval(input('Input the hour when you entered the parking lot(in 24h time please, no leading zeroes):'))
startMinute = input('Input the minute when you entered the parking lot: ')
endHour = eval(input('Input the hour when you exited the parking lot(in 24h time please, no leading zeroes): '))
endMinute = input('Input the hour when you exited the parking lot: ')
minutesPassed = (60*endHour + int(endMinute))-(60*startHour + int(startMinute))

k=1
if minutesPassed<=(15*k):
    k+=1
    halfHoursPassed=math.floor(float(minutesPassed)/30)
else:
    halfHoursPassed=math.ceil(float(minutesPassed)/30)


subtotal = halfHoursPassed * 1.75
total = subtotal * 1.13

print('*******')
print('Parkinglot')
print('Your time in was',str(startHour)+':'+ startMinute)
print('Your time out was',str(endHour)+':'+ endMinute)
print('You spent','%.0f' %halfHoursPassed,'half hours at our garages')
print('Your subtotal was $' + '%.2f' %subtotal)
print('Your total was $' + '%.2f' %total)
print('Thank you for your stay')
print('*******')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with `full_halves = int(minutesPassed / 30)` you can get the "full" 30 minute periods. Then using modulo operator `%` you get the remainer: `remaining = minutesPassed % 30`. Now, if this remainer is greater than 15, you should add another full half, otherwise you use the `full_halves` as is.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator `%` gives back the remainder after floor division `//`. That is to say that `7 // 3 == 2, 7 % 3 == 1`. Indeed these two are mutually defined such that `(x // k) * k + (x % k) == x`.

You should consider taking the modulo of your `minutesPassed` and 30 to see where the partial-half-hour lies, then comparing that with 15 to judge whether or not to round up or down.

```py
halfHoursPassed = minutesPassed // 30
if minutesPassed % 30 >= 15:
    halfHoursPassed += 1
```

You can somewhat simplify this by using the builtin `divmod`, which gives both `//` and `%` at once.

```py
halfHoursPassed, partialHalfHour = divmod(minutesPassed, 30)
if partialHalfHour >= 15:
    halfHoursPassed += 1
```